# How does Room notifies the UI that the data has changed?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have this query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Movie")
LiveData<List<Movie>> getAll();
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    @Inject AppDatabase db;
    private LiveData<List<Movie>> data;

    public MainActivityViewModel() {
        MovieApp.graph().inject(this);
        data = db.movieDao().getAll();
    }

    LiveData<List<Movie>> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And in onCreate of my Activity I call:

```
viewModel.getData().observe(this, adapter::setMovies);
```

In a [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html) I download a Json and convert it to [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) objects and call

```
db.movieDao().insertAll(movies.results);
```

but nothing happens :-(

Do I have to trigger a Room refresh manually or will Room it for me automatically? Do I miss something?

**Edit:**

I added some logout, this is what happens so far in this order:

- `MainActivityViewModel` created and calls `db.movieDao().getAll()`
- Activity observes ViewModel `viewModel.getData().observe(this, adapter::setMovies)`
- `setMovies` called with 0 data
- couple of seconds later JobService has started, loads data and calls `db.movieDao().insertAll(movies.results)`

At this point I expect a refresh call from Room because the DB data has changed but nothing happens.

Comment: `setMovies` does call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, right?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes. But it is only called once with no data and before the download has begun. When the download has finished it is not called again. When I restart the app I see the downloaded stuff from the previous run.

Comment: Are you using the same `RoomDatabase` instance in both places? For example, if your `JobService` is in a separate process from the UI code, by definition, those are separate `RoomDatabase`. instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CommonsWare. I forgot a `@Singleton` annotation in my Dagger module.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Rather than editing the question with the solution, though, consider posting your own answer to the question, then (later) marking it as accepted. This way, your question and its solution will be more obviously useful when it comes up in searches and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my app creates two Room instances because I forgot a [`@Singleton` annotation in my Dagger module](https://github.com/the4thfloor/PopularMovies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/udacity/nanodegree/popularmovies/di/AppModule.java#L27).